# How to use the result of SQL aggregate in IF statement

Tags: hana

I am trying to script a procedure in HANA, and I have a requirement to compare the Week ID's of 2 tables. If the `Week ID1 > Week ID2`, I have to insert the new records to table which has ID2. I tried the below logic, but that did not work.

Here, the logic inside the `IF` is not executing, though the

```
VAR1 VARCHAR(2);
VAR2 VARCHAR(2);
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(FISCAL_WK) AS VAR1 FROM "XXX"."OUTLOOK_FACTS";
    SELECT MAX(FISCAL_WK) AS VAR2 FROM "XXX"."OUTLOOK";
    IF :VAR2 > :VAR1 THEN
        SELECT MAX(OUTLOOKID) AS TEST FROM "XXX"."OUTLOOK_FACTS";
    END IF;
END;
```

I am pretty new to this, so please help.

Comment: If you are using Hana, why did you tag this with SQL Server? (which is a Microsoft product)

Comment: not sure if you can use > with varchars. Try casting/changing the values to int

Answer (score 0):

In your code example you don't actually assign values to :VAR1 or :VAR2, so both variables stay empty.

Try with

```
SELECT MAX(FISCAL_WK) AS VAR1 into :VAR1 FROM "XXX"."OUTLOOK_FACTS";
SELECT MAX(FISCAL_WK) AS VAR2 into :VAR2 FROM "XXX"."OUTLOOK";
IF :VAR2 > :VAR1 THEN
    SELECT MAX(OUTLOOKID) AS TEST FROM "XXX"."OUTLOOK_FACTS";
END IF;
```

You could, however also just pack everything in a single SQL statement. But that's for you do choose :)

Answer (score 0):

For that insert you don't need any procedural code.
You could do it in straight SQL:

```
select case 
       when max_fisc > max_fisc_fact then
           max_id_fact
       else
           -1
       end as VALUE_TO_BE_INSERTED
from (       
        select max(o.fiscal_wk) as max_fisc, max(o.outlookid) as max_id
            ,  max(f.fiscal_wk) as max_fisc_fact, max(f.outlookid) as max_id_fact
        from outlook o 
            cross join outlook_facts f);
```

Just pack this SQL into your INSERT statement and you're done.
- Lars